# How to avoid "new" in JavaScript factory function's documentation (or a better way to document its return type)?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

Let's say I have a factory function like this:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    return {name: name, age: age};
}
```

Using JSDoc3, I tried to document that function in the following way:

```
/** Creates a Person object
 * @param {String} name The name of the person
 * @param {Number} age The person's age in years
 * @returns {object} The Person object specified */
function Person() {...}
```

Obviously, this leads to the generation of the `Person` function's documentation as a **Method** and doesn't give any clues about the return object's structure.

Therefore I tried to document it as a class, like so:

```
/** Represents a person
 * @param {String} name The name of the person
 * @param {Number} age The person's age in years
 * @class*/
function Person(name, age) {
    return /** @lends Person.prototype */ {
        /** The name of the person */
        name: name, 
        /** The person's age in years */
        age: age
    };
}
```

Unfortunately (apart from the documentation comments not being DRY), documenting it as a class will result in the following text:

> ### Class: Person
>
> #### Person
>
> `new Person(name, age)`
> ...

Notice the **`new`** keyword there?

This is not how I intended the `Person` function to be called, instead I use it as in `var joe = Person("Joe", 24);`.

How can I get rid of the `new` keyword in the generated documentation?

### Update

Thanks for all the ideas/suggestions in the comments below, here is some additional information to clarify a couple of things:

- I am aware that it would've probably been better to use [real classes (custom objects)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects), which *do* use `new` to create. This question however is about **documenting** these existing factory functions using JSDoc3 in a way that leads to a useful API reference.
- I am aware that it is technically incorrect to label the `function Person` with `@class`, as it is not used as a class (doesn't take `new` to create an instance).  In the same way as it is technically incorrect to use `@lends Person.prototype` (thanks [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871965/how-to-avoid-new-in-javascript-factory-functions-documentation?noredirect=1#comment63200928_37871965) for pointing this out), as the `prototype` of `Person` is not involved.  Again, I did this for documentation purposes to have the fields of a person instance documented in a linkable fashion.
- As suggested by [@Bálint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871965/how-to-avoid-new-in-javascript-factory-functions-documentation?noredirect=1#comment63200677_37871965) and [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871965/how-to-avoid-new-in-javascript-factory-functions-documentation?noredirect=1#comment63201129_37871965), I could document the `Person`'s return type (i.e. the person instance structure) within the `Person`'s `@returns` tag.  This puts me back to my first attempt, in which a person instance documentation is just a textual description and I am not sure I can link to its members from other points in the documentation:

If `Person` is documented as a `@class`, I can e.g. create references to a person (and its fields) documentation like so:

```
/** Produces an array of {@link Person}s, sorted by their {@link Person#age}.
 * @param {Array} persons The persons to sort
 * @returns {Array} The sorted persons*/
function sortPersonsByAge(persons) {
    return persons.sort(function(a, b) {return a.age - b.age;});
}
```

If I leave the `Person`'s documentation as a method (as the very first attempt above) and put all the information about a person's object structure inside its `@returns` documentation tag, how can I link to the type and its fields/methods from elsewhere, as in the `sortPersonsByAge` example?

Comment: Classes are constructed with `new`, so it's not a class, you have a factory function, which raises the question of why the name is capitalized like a constructor, but...

Comment: factory functions should be named `create_xyz`

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I wasn't aware of any capitalisation guidelines regarding factory methods - in fact, **[this site](http://javascript.info/tutorial/factory-constructor-pattern)** suggests I am correct, but I am always ready to learn... surely that doesn't affect the question though?

Comment: Maybe write something like "returns a new person object". Because this is a method, wich returns a new person object.

Comment: Protip: if a site says "like Python" to JavaScript, then avoid it.

Comment: @Bálint this matches my first attempt mentioned in my question, but raises the question of how to document the person object's structure?

Comment: Put it in the return description

Comment: @Bálint If you could give a complete example, specifically one where I can refer to a person's object (and its fields/methods) from elsewhere in the documentation, I'll be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: One of your documentation comments says `/** @lends Person.prototype */`, but in fact your `Person()` function returns an object that is not in any way connected to `Person.prototype` or `Person`. (Regarding capitalisation, there is a long-standing convention in JS that functions that start with an uppercase letter are intended to be called with `new`. Obviously there is no *technical* requirement for you to follow this convention, and *any* JS function can be called with `new`, but if you don't follow the convention your code could confuse other people.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I did this in order to document a person instance's object structure. Similarly, decorating the `Person` method as a `@class` is technically incorrect, as it is just a factory method. Again, I haven't found a better way to document both the function *and* its returned type properly - that would exactly be my question... maybe I should edit it to clarify.

Comment: At this point, constructors without `new` is essentially an anti-pattern, and going forward all new native constructors are requiring the use of `new`. If you are making a factory function, that's fine, but you might want to checkout custom objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Can't you say something like `@returns an object with properties: name, age`? (Better than nothing, and better than misusing @class or other options.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37913368/897968) didn't lead to `function` members of the [@typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) being documented at all, I resorted to the [@namespace](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-namespace.html) tag instead:

```
/** Creates a {@link PersonObj}
 * @param {String} name The name of the person
 * @param {Number} age The person's age in years
 * @return {PersonObj} The new person object */
function Person(name, age) {
    /** Represents a person. Use the {@link Person} function to create one.
     * @namespace PersonObj */
    return p = {
        /** The name of the person 
         * @memberof PersonObj# */
        name: name, 
        /** The person's age in years
         * @memberof PersonObj# */
        age: age,
        /** Displays a greeting 
         * @memberof PersonObj# 
         * @param {String} otherName Name of another person */
        greet: function(otherName) {
            alert('Hello '+otherName+', my name is '+p.name);
        }
    };
}
```

One advantage of this pattern is that the type's member documentation is now closer to where they are actually defined in the source.

One disadvantage is that the [@memberof](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html) tag seems to be required for the members to show up in the documentation of the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that seems both technically correct *and* producing nice documentation is provided via the [@typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) tag, which can be used to document the return type separately from the factory function.

Within the `@typedef`, the [@property](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-property.html) tag can be used to define the fields:

```
/** Represents a person. Use the {@link Person} function to create one.
 * @typedef PersonObj
 * @property {String} name The name of the person
 * @property {Number} name The person's age in years */
```

Then, a link to that type can be added to e.g. the factory function's documentation:

```
/** Creates a {@link PersonObj}
 * @param {String} name The name of the person
 * @param {Number} age The person's age in years
 * @return {PersonObj} The new person object */
function Person(name, age) {
    return {
        name: name, 
        age: age
    };
}
```

Hope someone else finds this helpful.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to generate documentation for `function` members of the `PersonObj` type.